# CefSharp RegisterJsObject throw StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I currently was facing an issue when using CefSharp RegisterJsObject. My code as below.

I am using

```
<package id="cef.redist.x64" version="3.2704.1432" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="cef.redist.x86" version="3.2704.1432" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="CefSharp.Common" version="51.0.0-pre02" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="CefSharp.WinForms" version="51.0.0-pre02" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Program.cs

```
namespace Project1
{
    public static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        private static void Main()
        {
            Initialize();

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            var cefSettings = new CefSettings
            {
                UserAgent =
                    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36"
            };
            Cef.Initialize(cefSettings);

            new FormSplash().Show();
            Application.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

FormSplash.cs

```
namespace Project1
{
    public partial class FormSplash : Form
    {
        public ChromiumWebBrowser Browser { get; set; }
        public JsObject JsObj { get; set; }

        public FormSplash()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            JsObj = new JsObject(this);
        }

        private void FormChromeToneExcelRegistration_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://google.com");
            Browser.RegisterJsObject("jsObj", new JsObject(this));
            Browser.FrameLoadStart += Browser_FrameLoadStart;
            Browser.FrameLoadEnd += Browser_FrameLoadEnd;
            Controls.Add(Browser);
            Browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }

        private void SetMessage(string message)
        {
            ...
        }

        public class JsObject
        {
            public FormSplash Form { get; set; }

            public JsObject(FormSplash form)
            {
                Form = form;
            }

            public void SetMessage(string message)
            {
                Form.SetMessage(message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I keep on getting `An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll` with no inner exception details on the line **RegisterJsObject**.

Scenario I've also tried:

- Change the *SetMessage* to *setMessage* (not work)
- Moved the nested class out (not work)

I've tried these code below and its work.

```
Browser.RegisterJsObject("jsObj", "");
Browser.RegisterJsObject("jsObj", new {});
Browser.RegisterJsObject("jsObj", new DateTime());
```

Can please help me why the class that in my project will throw StackOverflowException?

Comment: Make your form property private or add the `JavascriptIgnoreAttribute` attribute to the property.

Comment: thanks @amaitland. it's work now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @amaitland. The solution for this was either make the `Form` in `JsObject` as private or make it as `JavascriptIgnoreAttribute`